# luigi doesn't work with alias

Tags: bash, luigi

I'm trying to create an alias for my luigi task. Usually to invoke it I'd type out `luigi --module myTask --parameters cats`

However, I want to create an alias to shorten it to `myTask --parameters cats`, so I went to my `.bash_profile` and put this `alias myTask='luigi --module myTask "$@"'`

However, when I try invoking my task again with the alias, I get this error:
    luigi.task_register.TaskClassNotFoundException: No task myTask. Candidates are: Config,ExternalTask,RangeBase,RangeDaily,RangeDailyBase,RangeHourly,RangeHourlyBase,Task,WrapperTask,core,execution_summary,retcode,scheduler,worker

Am I missing something in my `.bash_profile` to make this alias work?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to point to the directory in which `myTask` is located. So you could change your alias to something like:

`alias myTask='PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/myTask/dir luigi --module myTask "$@"'`

Or, you could export the path somewhere in your `.bash_profile`:

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/myTask/dir`